# [mxgraph]Preventing Parent Element from Covering Default Child Component Tooltip when Using highlight() Method

Tags: mxgraph

How to prevent the parent element from covering the default tooltip of the child component when the parent element uses the highlight() method?

The tooltip added to the parent element using highlight() will cover the default green tooltip of the child element when hovering over the parent element.